# iptables and skype

Tags: skype, iptables

Does anyone here use `iptables` with `skype`? The only way I have been able to get it working so far is to allow all the high ports- something like

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p UDP --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

which is obviously less than ideal. The problem is as far as I can tell the ports `skype` uses are somewhat random. I was hoping it might be possible to allow application level firewalling by using `setuid` or `setguid`, for example

```
sudo addgroup skypeGrp
sudo usermod theUser -G skypeGrp
sudo chgrp skypeGrp /usr/bin/skype
chmod g+s /usr/bin/skype
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner skypeGrp -j ACCEPT
```

but this didn't seem to work.

Perhaps other have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it up to allow all outbound.  And then allow related/established as one of the first rules.

Something like:

```
# Accept loopback & established/related connections
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Drop invalid on tcp
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# Set default DROP policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# But allow everything out
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Now set what you want to allow in.

# e.g. SSH in
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Doesn't Skype need an inbound port though? or does th `-m conntrack` somehow take care of that?Also what is the `-A always` chain, I have never come across that one.

Comment: Connection tracking will take care of related/established connections so they won't get dropped.  Try it out.  Sorry about the always chain... it was copied & modified from some rules I have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So just checking I understand: is this basic idea that `skype` will first connect on some outbound port (which we have allowed), say port 38768 then once this connection is established `-m conntrack` will allow skype to form related inbound connections too on say 15672?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: By the way, this is for an individual machine.  If this is for a router, then you'll be dealing with the FORWARD chain too.  As INPUT chain only deals with data destined to the machine (not through).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience if you allow all outgoing trafic you can make calls but you cant receive calls from others unless you open a port for incoming connections.

In Skype 4.2.0.11
Go to

Skype > Options > Advanced > Connections

You can decide what port skype uses. It was 7004 by default.

I think you need to allow both tcp and udp.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7004 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 7004 -j ACCEPT
```